# Reference SQLite layer in QGIS by 'layername' instead of 'layerid'

Tags: qgis, sqlite, vector-layer

In QGIS, when I add a vector layer from a SQLite database, the "Layer Source" in the properties dialogue is referenced by 'layerid':

`C:/lookup.sqlite|layerid=4`

However, what I want to do, and, what happens by default on my colleagues computer when they add the same vector layer from the same SQLite database the "Layer Source" is referenced by 'layername':

`C:/lookup.sqlite|layername=roadsegments`

I am using QGIS 2.18.7.  My colleague is using QGIS 2.12.  Is the reference method to an SQLite an option that can be set, or, related to the version of QGIS, or, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you load the SpatiaLite layer, QGIS generates different layer source strings.

If you load the layer dragging it from the browser to the layers pane, QGIS shows a layer source string like `C:/lookup.sqlite|layerid=4`.

If you load the layer using the menu option `Layer -> Add layer -> Add SpatiaLite Layer...` (or the feather button in the Manage Layers Toolbar) the generated layer source string is different: `'dbname="C:/lookup.sqlite" table="roadsegments" (Geometry) sql='`.

In PyQGIS I use this layer source string as the vector layer URI and it loads OK.

For more information check the SpatiaLite section of "Loading layers" in PyQGIS Developer Cookbook:  https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html